# Cannot read serial Data to tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I am trying to read data from a serial device but I am only receiving blank data or None type data back. While if I just used a normal string of random data it works fine. Not really sure where to go from here.

```
import tkinter as tk

import serial

import time
import datetime



def serialData():
    serialPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
    baudRate = 115200
    
    ser = serial.Serial(serialPort, baudRate, timeout=1)
    print(ser)
    swiftData = ser.readline().decode('ascii', errors='replace')
    print(swiftData)
    return swiftData

def newSerialData():
    return

def outputData():
    
    serialData()
    root.after(200, outputData)



root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Test #6")
root.geometry("1200x800")

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)






root.after(200, outputData)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the output? Did it receive correctly and it does not do it now? Also please add the desired output

Comment: This would be my desired output: "$GPGGA,214201.40,4915.4230528,N,12243.8653376,W,2,13,1.6,-13.23,M,0.0,M,,*69" . Currently I am just recieving a None Type

Comment: Try adding your string to a Label, not to root.after

Comment: Try moving the creation of `ser` out of `serialData()`, i.e. create the `ser` in main block.

Comment: Alright that seems to work thx

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the serial connection state

```
ser = serial.Serial(serialPort, baudRate, timeout=1)
if ser.is_open:
   # do something
else:
   # error
```

Comment: I am able to read serial data when I am not using the code for tkinter its just within tkinter where I get a None type